# using icons in github repository description field

Tags: github

Some repositories have icons in their description.

For example https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet is using

> :leaves:

Where is that documented ?

Comment: To whoever downvoted this question: why is it a stupid question ? How can you know something before your learn it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly related to github. It is supporting emoji as a lot of other sites are doing it.

see the following link for the github markdown
[github markdown](https://markdown-it.github.io/)

see the following link for the complete list of the emoji that can be used
[emoji-cheat-sheet](http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/)